# ORA-00911: invalid character (Oracle Data Provider for .NET, Managed Driver)

Tags: sql, oracle, reporting-services

I am having this issue while executing this oracle in SSRS re

Query is:

```
SELECT something
FROM   x
WHERE  productid <> 'Cash'
       AND va.principal IN (WITH t
                                 AS (SELECT ? STR
                                     FROM   dual)
                            SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR (str, '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL)
                                   SPLIT_VALUES
                             FROM   t
                             CONNECT BY LEVEL <= (SELECT LENGTH (
                                                 Replace (str, ',',
                                                 NULL))
                                                  FROM   t))
ORDER  BY cusip,
          portfolio
```

---

Comment: With statement needs to preceded entire statement

Comment: You either use a subquery OR a CTE. You have somehow managed to do both.

Comment: @xQbert: no it does not: http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=20f08aa2eb9e883f68000a0e71beacc7

Comment: News to me!  learned something new.

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite your query to look something like this.

```
SELECT something
FROM   x va
       JOIN (WITH t
                  AS (SELECT ? STR
                      FROM   dual)
             SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR (str, '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL) split_values
              FROM   t
              CONNECT BY LEVEL <= (SELECT Length (REPLACE (str, ',', NULL))
                                   FROM   t)) b
         ON va.principal = b.split_values
WHERE  productid <> 'Cash'
ORDER  BY cusip,
          portfolio;
```

Comment: Thanks for your time. My main concern was that I was not able to extract comma separated values from SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR (str, '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL) while passing parameters from SSRS Report Builder. So I found a workaround to resolve. I set the condition in expression block of tablix properties. But this affects the performance.